# Excel Macro: Copy specific cells from multiple sheets to specific cells in separate sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to Excel macros but have recently tried them out and find them really useful. The problem is my programming knowledge is limited to Matlab so I'm wondering if someone can suggest a macro for the following problem.

I have collected study data and I want to move it all to one Excel spreadsheet. Each sheet has data for on participant, and there are 67 sheets. The sort of macro which would be useful is one which looks in the same five cells (always D36:D40) of 67 sheets and copies it to a specific part of a row in the new sheet (AKx, ALx, AMx, ANx, AOx where x is the next row down, starting from 3, for every sheet data is copied from).

I feel by code being provided for my specific situation it will be easier for me to understand what the code does and thus I can slowly start to learn some macro code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a macro for that.  You can just include the file name in the cell referencing.

The formula looks like this:

```
='file:///C:/[path and filename].xlsx'#$'[sheetname]'.G22
```

The easiest way to accomplish this is to have both sheets open.  In your main sheet, type the "=" and ALT-TAB to the other sheet, click on the cell you wish to reference.  Hit return.  The value from that cell will appear in your main sheet.

So your main file, can point to those 60 some-odd sheets, and whatever cells you want. Any time you update those files, your main sheet will always be up to date.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Seems I'm misunderstanding something. I go on the main file and type in = and then go to the other spread sheet, all sheets are already highlighted with ALT-TAB from me doing it before, then I select on cell I want. The end result is only the first of the main file has now the same value as one cell in one of the 67 results documents. Hence I would need to repeat this 67 times. I am clearly misunderstanding something. Any ideas what this could be? "='[WM+VSTM_Results_All.xlsm]01'!$D$36" - this is example of what the end reference looks like. Thanks

Comment: Yes.  You would have to repeat that operation 67 times.  Or, to make it more simple, you can manually change the reference file name in the cell.  I only suggested the shortcut method to get you started.  The upshot is that once your references are all set, your "master" document will be complete.

Comment: Okay I see, although I was be prepared to do this, the small issue is I have another 9 cells I want to copy from each of the 67 result documents meaning I will do this 603 times. Also although I agree it is nice that the "master" document will always get updated, the values in the results document will not change as this is data from a study. Therefore, I am okay to change this 603 times, but I feel that I am not achieving my aim of wanting to reduce time inputting data. My other peers in research do this but I am interested in idea of using coding to save time. So would macro be needed now?

Comment: In either case you're going to have to manually reference those files, whether you type them out in a macro, or put them in a cell formula.  What I suggest is to do all 9 cells in the sheet once, then duplicate them.  Then do a "search and replace" to reference the filenames and change them all at once.  It would go amazingly quickly that way.

Comment: Okay nice idea - I like this. So I just went to try it and got everything set in place meaning I made all the cells in a column called "='[WM+VSTM_Results_All.xlsm]24'!$A$44" which reference the 24th participant's data. I did this for all 9 columns so that all the columns reference a different cell each. Then I highlighted first row and tried to replace "]24'!$A$" with "]01!$A$" so that all columns change to first participant (i.e., columns cells identified by $44 meaning all nine of them will change). However, replace doesn't seem to include the ref info not in actual excel sheet.

Comment: Okay durbnpoisn please ignore my previous comment - I have now applied your idea and it worked brilliantly! I had the issue I mentioned in the previous comment because I had some sheet names contain extra spaces which I was not aware of but after changing this the problem was solved. And I realised the replace function does replace information in formulas. I'm really liking this forum and glad I found it. I look forward to learning more about programming, though in this case it was more about learning to use Excel more efficiently which is interesting too.